# String_Split example not working for me, says insufficient parameters

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2016 and latest SSMS, I'm trying to take a csv string and split it and then insert into table-value parameter variable and I'm getting error squiggles under the string_split function.

Is what I'm doing even possible?

```
DECLARE @tvParam TABLE (FirstName nvarchar(50))

DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = '0152,1731'

INSERT INTO @tvParam 
    SELECT Value 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s, ',')
```

[image]

Comment: What does "latest SSMS" mean? I am using 18.11.1 and don't see this warning message (which, again, you can ignore).

Comment: At least 18.10 but I’m AFK ATM

Comment: 18.11.1 should handle that function better. But as I explain below, it won't change the _behavior_ or the _result_. If you have an issue with the _result_, post that as a different question.

Comment: What happens if you right click and choose show parameter info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what build of SSMS you're using but that is just IntelliSense being not so intelligent. In anticipation of [these changes to that function](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7039/stringsplit-function-azure-sql-database-ordinal-position/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), IntelliSense was updated to expect 3 parameters unconditionally. It doesn't understand (a) that the 3rd parameter is optional, and (b) where it's even supported. Current/future builds of SSMS should get better at this over time.

Here is SSMS 18.11.1:

> [image]

Thankfully, you can ignore the message, which is just a parse-time warning. [The code *runs* successfully](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=17eb6e12620695cdfd4e91e2d8cd7a1b).

Comment: I’m using latest SSMS and I thought I tried all the different combinations 0,1,Null and wasn’t getting expected result. I’ll double check when I get back home.

Comment: @Rod if you're not getting the expected result, that's certainly a different problem than the erroneous error message. Make sure you are really using "latest" ([18.11.1 was released in March](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)), but that will only affect the IntelliSense and tooltip, not behavior.

Comment: You were right, error was somewhere else

Comment: BTW, if you right click on the squiggles there's Intellisense Enabled and it will get rid of the squiggles for that session

Comment: @Rod Sure, you can disable IntelliSense, but it is correct and arguably useful 99% of the time, so it's kind of like throwing away your TV because you saw one commercial you didn't like.